# How to Upload Files using ajax call in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have created a small asp.net web forms application, to manage emails , i have created a little interface contains mandatory information to send a email, like from , to , subject etc. now i want to attach files to the email, i have used asp.net file upload controller to upload files,
and have to attach multiple files,

[image: Interface]

Now i want to send this details to code behind, so i thought the best way is to use ajax calls , because i don't want to refresh my page, but i can't figure out the way how to send the attached files to the server side,
i have read some articles and they saying i have to use `FormData` to send the files ,
then i have created a `FormData` object and appended all the attached files to the object.but how to pass this object to server side,
my js code as below,

```
function sendEmail() {

    var data = new FormData();
    var files = $('.attachment');
    $.each(files, function (key, value) {
        var file = $(value).data('file');
        data.append(file.name, file);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "OpenJobs.aspx/sendEmail",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
        processData: false, // Not to process data  
        data: null,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        }
    });

}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Generic handler to upload files using ajax, try below code:

```
function sendEmail() {

var formData = new FormData();
var files = $('.attachment');
$.each(files, function (key, value) {
    var file = $(value).data('file');
    formData.append(file.name, file);
});

$.ajax({
    url: "FileUploadHandler.ashx",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
    processData: false, // Not to process data  
    data: formData,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    }
});
}
```

**Generic handler**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="FileUploadHandler" %>    

using System;    
using System.Web;    

public class FileUploadHandler : IHttpHandler  
{    

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)  
{    
    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)    
    {    
        HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;    
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)    
        {    
            HttpPostedFile file = files[i];    
            string fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + file.FileName);    
            file.SaveAs(fname);    
        }    
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";      
    }    

}      
}
```

Comment: Is there any alternative way without using Generic Handler?

Comment: Unfortunately not at this stage. Tried Various suggestion made on multiple forums. In the end the generic event handler just works.