# Passing an Excel file to server using AJAX Post

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-ajax

I simply want to be able to use a html Input type="file" to select an Excel file

```
<input type="file" id="UploadedFile" name="UploadedFile" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">
```

then pass that chosen file back to the server - preferably using AJAX post:

```
    var serviceURL = appRoot + 'Register/ImportTasks'

    $j.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: serviceURL,
        data: (??? Not sure how to present here ???),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });
```

Specifically I cannot see how I present the 'file' to the AJAX call as data.

```
    public void ImportTasks(DataType?? uploadedExcelFile)
    {
        ..... Doing stuff ...
    }
```

And then I am unsure as to what parameter datatype I should then tell the Method to expect when it is called?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/upload-files-through-jquery-ajax-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery ajax upload file in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428296/jquery-ajax-upload-file-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: This does look promising actually....! I will probably take a look in the morning and will update! Many thanks for the quick response...! Really appreciate it! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475698/how-to-upload-files-using-ajax-call-in-asp-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic example. You should use `FormData`

```
     var formData = new FormData();
     var uploadFiles = document.getElementById('js-upload-files').files;
     this.formData.append("MyKey", uploadFiles[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Controller/Upload',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        complete: this.onComplete.bind(this)
    });
```

Edit

Forgot controller code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual BetterJsonResult Upload()
    {

        foreach (var fileKey in Request.Files)
        {
            ...Request.Files[fileKey.ToString()] //access it like this
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks - this and a couple of other similar suggestions have gotten this working for me.